# how to fix error : "NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays"

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am developing a web with Angular 4 and connect with Firebase. However, I have an error "NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays" and I do not know how to fix it. Can anyone help me?
Thank you very much

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
>   'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

product.service.ts :

```
  public productCollection : AngularFirestoreCollection<Product[]>;    
  public products ;

  constructor( public fs : AngularFirestore) {

  }
  getAllProducts(){

    return this.products;
  }
}
```

product-list.component.ts

```
constructor(
    public productService : ProductService,
    public firestore : AngularFirestore
  ) { 
    this.products = firestore.collection('products').valueChanges().subscribe((data )=>{
      this.products = data;
     console.log(this.products);
  })    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.productService.getAllProducts();
    this.firestore.collection('products').valueChanges().subscribe((data) =>{
    this.products = data
    console.log(this.productService);
    });
```

product.component.html

```
<tr  *ngFor = "let item of products"  [routerLink] = "['/products',item.number]" >
      <td>{{item.number}}</td>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.location}}</td>  
      <td>{{item.status ? 'Deliverd' : 'Storage'}}</td>  
    </tr>
```

Comment: Your subscribe and your actual products need to be different things, it doesn't make sense to `this.products = ...subscribe(..this.products = data;`. What is products the subscription or the data? It can't be both

Answer (score 0):

Your products has to be the data (`Array<product>`) not the subscription.
You should fix your component where you are getting list of `products`:

```
constructor(
    public productService : ProductService,
    public firestore : AngularFirestore
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
   this.products = this.productService.getAllProducts();
    this.firestore.collection('products').valueChanges().subscribe((data) =>{
       this.products = data
       console.log(this.products); // Or update your products by making another service call
    });
```

Comment: I solved the problem. just change 'data' to 'firestore' and it works. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, just change "data" to "firestore". Thank you everybody for helping me.

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.products = this.productService.getAllProducts();
    this.firestore.collection('products').valueChanges().subscribe((firestore) =>{
       this.products = firestore
       console.log(this.products); 
    });
```